# Proguard: keepclassmembers inside a Namespace

Tags: java, android, obfuscation, proguard

I'm trying to obfuscate my Android app. After obfuscating, there are a few things broken, so I need to keep all classmembernames inside a special namespace.

what did't worked was

```
-keepclassmembers class my.namespace.to.keep** {*;}
```

any suggestion? It is no Problem if the whole class is kept or only its members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't tell in what way it didn't work, but you may need to specify -keep instead of -keepclassmembers.

You can specify -printseeds to see which classes and class members are matched by the -keep options.